# Is there a way to export only the Firestore delta or changes (the differences) since the last export?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, export, google-cloud-functions

I am doing a daily export of my Firestore records to Google's bucket storage using this scheduled export code (cron): https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export#deploy_the_app_and_cron_job

Is there a feature or code or API that is available yet to export only the delta differences or the changes made since the last export or does it only do full backups all the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not currently a way to do incremental backups.  The export mechanism described in the documentation is not really a "backup" in the way that most people would think of that word.  It's just an export, to be used to make it easy to recover from disaster, or make copies to bootstrap other databases for immediate use.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson
I am not using it for disaster recovery per-se but using it to create reports in BigQuery. I was looking for a more efficient way to do this. I guess I will have to explore data streamlining (pub/sub) method or create new functions to write directly to BQ. Thanks!

Comment: You could also use Cloud Functions to mirror changes to documents in Firestore into BigQuery, in real time, if that's what you're hoping to do. That is a common use case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach to get the segmented data using a temporary collection `/exportData`

> Reminder that the necessary read, write, & delete calls for this still fall under standard billable usage

As part of the scheduled script, run following **async** sequence:

1. Empty collection `/exportData`
2. Run a filtered query to get the delta data
3. Write the delta data you want to export to collection `/exportData`
4. Export just that collection `/exportData`

As per the docs *"You can export all documents or just specific collections."*  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import